# Truffle Pet Store migration.sol compile error

Tags: truffle

I'm trying to run the Truffle Petshop example: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

But either the Migrations.sol won't compile or the writing artifacts fails.  I can't determine which from the error. The output indicates that Adoption.sol compiles, then Migrations.sol, which was provided in the project template, does not compile. Clearly, the project template is correct, so what would cause the error?

I'm running PowerShell with elevated rights on Windows 7.0.

Thanks in advance

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Documents\Code\BlockChainCode\pet-shop-box-master> truffle compile
    Compiling .\contracts\Adoption.sol...
    Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol...
    5
    truffle : 5
    At line:1 char:1
    + truffle compile
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (5:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError



C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:48
            throw e;
            ^
    abort(5) at Error
        at jsStackTrace (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1:19718)
        at stackTrace (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1:19901)
        at abort (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:19:15285)
        at Array.dXb (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:11:585101)
        at Array.tX (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:8:557453)
        at Array.eea (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:6:495332)
        at Object.wOb [as dynCall_ii] (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:11:540050)
        at invoke_ii (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1:1275129)
        at Array.ixa (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:7:494308)
        at Object.bVb [as dynCall_viii] (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:11:577232)
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Truffle version and it solved the problem.